# Remove elasticity from NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have an NSView (It contains few text boxes and buttons etc).

Now introduced in MAC OS X Lion is an elasticity effect just like iPhone e.g. safari

My question is how can I remove that elasticity effect from my NSView?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know about Mac, but for iPhone you can just set bounces content to NO. I believe that there is a `setVerticalScrollElasticity` method you would pass `NSScrollElasticityNone` (horizontal is the same).

Comment: Thanks Dustin. I just tried myView.enclosingScrollView.verticalScroller = NO;
    myView.enclosingScrollView.verticalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticityNone;
    myView.enclosingScrollView.horizontalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticityNone; but in vain. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: As far as I know that's the only thing you have to do. All I can suggest is making sure you're referencing the correct scrollview and that you're actually changing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `NSScrollView` and go to **Attributes Inspector** and change from **Automatic Elasticity** to **No Elasticity** like this:

[image]

Comment: I had to put my NSView under NSScrollView and then it's all fine. Thanks Everyone.